# Refreshing grid data on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have this code. In here I am retrieving a new set of values via a URL through Jquery Ajax($.get()) on calling a function gotoa() on some click event. I am obtaining the set of values correctly as i am getting right result on alert. But the grid is not updating itself at that moment. When i refresh the whole page then the grid updates. How to update the grid on calling of gotoa() itself. ?

The code ::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gotoa(){
    $.get("http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/jsp/GetJson.jsp?random=" + new Date().getTime(), function(result){

            alert(result);
            var storedata={
                identifier:"ID",
                label:"name",
                items:result
        };


    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: storedata});
    alert(store);
    //var gridh = dijit.byId("gridDiv");
    //gridh.setStore(store);


        var gridStructure =[[

                          { field: "ID",
                                name: "ID_Emp",
                                width: "20%",
                                classes:"firstname"
                          },
                          {
                              field: "Names",
                              name: "Name",
                              width: "20%",
                              classes: "firstname"
                          },
                          { field: "Email",
                                name: "Mail",
                                width: "20%",
                                classes:"firstname"
                          }

                    ]
              ];


         var grid1 = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
                id: 'grid2',
                store: store,
                structure: gridStructure,
                rowSelector: '30px',
                selectionMode: "single",
                autoHeight:true,
                columnReordering:true},
              document.createElement('div'));

            /*append the new grid to the div*/
            dojo.byId("gridDiv").appendChild(grid1.domNode);

            /*Call startup() to render the grid*/
            grid1.startup();

         // assuming our grid is stored in a variable called "myGrid":
            dojo.connect(grid1, "onSelectionChanged", grid1, function(){
                var items = grid1.selection.getSelected();



            //  do something with the selected items
                dojo.forEach(items, function(item){
                    var v = grid1.store.getValue(item, "Names");

                    function showDialog() {
                        dojo.require('dijit.Tooltip');
                        dijit.byId("terms").show();
                    }
                    //if(name!="Mail")
                    showDialog();
                    }, grid1);

            });


            dojo.connect(grid1, "onCellClick", grid1, function sendmail(){
                var items = grid1.selection.getSelected();

                dojo.forEach(items, function(item){
                    var v1 = grid1.store.getValue(item, "Email");      
                    alert(v1);
                    request.setAttribute("variablemail", v1);
            });

        });


    },"text");

    }

</script>
```

The output of alert(result) at a particular point of time is like this ::

```
[{"ID":1,"Names":"Shantanu","Email":"shantanu.tomar@gmail.com"},{"ID":2,"Names":"Mayur","Email":"mayur.sharma@gmail.com"},{"ID":3,"Names":"Rohit"},{"ID":4,"Names":"Jasdeep"},{"ID":5,"Names":"Rakesh","Email":"rakesh.shukla@gmail.com"},{"ID":6,"Names":"Divyanshu"},{"ID":8,"Names":"hello"},{"ID":9,"Names":"fine"},{"ID":10,"Names":"shivani"}]
```

And the output of alert(store) is like ::

```
[object Object]
```

And i am calling gotoa() on clicking anywhere inside a content pane(for the time being, later on will put a button or something) like this ::

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Pending Activities" style="background-image: url('http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/images/17.png');" onClick="gotoa();">
```

How to upgrade grid data ? thanks.

Comment: check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761027/updating-refereshing-dojo-datagrid-with-new-store-value-on-combobox-value-change

Comment: Hey i have edited something... Please check it again ..

Comment: what is the exact requirement/flow of your page?

Comment: Displaying data from Access database in a data grid . When changes are made in the Database they are reflected in grid at the same time on some click event rather refreshing the whole page again ... This is what i want to do .

Comment: So you want to show a grid initially, and when a user clicks on some element you want to refresh/reload the content of that grid rit?

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie to dojo, i think this code will help you::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gotoa(isUpdate){
    $.get("http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/jsp/GetJson.jsp?random=" + new Date().getTime(), function(result){

            alert(result);
            var storedata={
                identifier:"ID",
                label:"name",
                items:result
        };


    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: storedata});
    alert(store);
    if (isUpdate) {
       var grid = dojo.byId('grid2');
       grid.setStore(store);
    } else {


        var gridStructure =[[

                          { field: "ID",
                                name: "ID_Emp",
                                width: "20%",
                                classes:"firstname"
                          },
                          {
                              field: "Names",
                              name: "Name",
                              width: "20%",
                              classes: "firstname"
                          },
                          { field: "Email",
                                name: "Mail",
                                width: "20%",
                                classes:"firstname"
                          }

                    ]
              ];


         var grid1 = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
                id: 'grid2',
                store: store,
                structure: gridStructure,
                rowSelector: '30px',
                selectionMode: "single",
                autoHeight:true,
                columnReordering:true},
              document.createElement('div'));

            /*append the new grid to the div*/
            dojo.byId("gridDiv").appendChild(grid1.domNode);

            /*Call startup() to render the grid*/
            grid1.startup();

         // assuming our grid is stored in a variable called "myGrid":
            dojo.connect(grid1, "onSelectionChanged", grid1, function(){
                var items = grid1.selection.getSelected();



            //  do something with the selected items
                dojo.forEach(items, function(item){
                    var v = grid1.store.getValue(item, "Names");

                    function showDialog() {
                        dojo.require('dijit.Tooltip');
                        dijit.byId("terms").show();
                    }
                    //if(name!="Mail")
                    showDialog();
                    }, grid1);

            });


            dojo.connect(grid1, "onCellClick", grid1, function sendmail(){
                var items = grid1.selection.getSelected();

                dojo.forEach(items, function(item){
                    var v1 = grid1.store.getValue(item, "Email");      
                    alert(v1);
                    request.setAttribute("variablemail", v1);
            });

        });
        }

    });

    }

</script>
```

use `gotoa()` for initial loading of grid and `gotoa(true)` for updating the grid.

Comment: Where to initialize isUpdate ? and its initial value. ?

Comment: if you want to display the grid on page load use

$(document).ready(function (){
      gotoa();
});

and on click you want to update it so use

<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Pending Activities" style="background-image: url('http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/images/17.png');" onClick="gotoa(true);">

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736725/data-is-not-getting-displayed-in-dojox-data-datagrid-on-click-event